# compiling the yolo darknet source code in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, yolo, darknet

I want to compile darknet yolov3 source code in Qt to train a costum network.

I downloaded the official sources code from https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/.
I can compile darknet by **make** command on my ubuntu  and detect objects successsfully on **CPU**.

Now I want to compile darknet source code in Qt.

I added all the .c and .h files in the src and examples and include folders of darknet in my Qt project. But when i run my project , i have some errors like this :

[image: This picture shoes my problem]

This is my project .pro file :

[image]

I don't know why the darknet can be compiled on terminal but can not be compiled in Qt.

I searched a lot but there is no same problem and solutions.
What is my problem?

Comment: how your .pro....

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for your answer. My .pro is some thing like this :
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

And some added .h and .c files.
Can you tell me that what is my mistake?

Comment: edit your question and add it there since as you see the comments are not the right places to place code

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc .I edited it rightow.

Comment: change `network net = ...` to `network *net = ...`

Comment: @eyllanesc should i do this for all ofmy  errors??But why this code can be compiled with **make** command without problem?